# Excel duplicate value check for continious 3column in a row

Tags: excel

I want to print YES if there is a value greater than 5 and this value must be present alongside cells for at least 3 times.

As for example, in the attached image, I want to print YES if there is at least 3time continuous value (in this case 6,7 and 7.2) and this value must be greater than 5.

[image: Spreadsheet]

Comment: What have you tried? Please include a code example or attempt a formula and we can help. Is 4 the maximum number of cells?

Comment: The biggest problem is the OP contradicts themselves - leaving two entirely different interpretations. 3 Consecutive > 5 - or just 3+ >5 on a count. - Image and second statement tally. First does not. I felt I wasted time on this by answering this weighting it on the thing that was mentioned twice. And got downvote in process. I hate this kind of thing with SO.

Comment: to make sure they are consecutive and above 5 use: `=IF(COUNTIFS(A2:B2,">5",B2:C2,">5",C2:D2,">5"),"Yes","No")`  If there are more than 4 columns you would increase the size of the references not the number.

Comment: No that would then require there be 3 consecutive groupings of three above 5. Op only asked for one. @JGFMK

Comment: @ScottCraner Right using COUNTIFS like this is a bit of a brain teaser. Somehow is that passing back 0 to the outer IF (or false?) in order that No is the net result. If you broke your formula down into a result per comparison for data given in image above, you would have 1,2,2 resolving to Yes. (because of a non zero # I guess). If data was 6 5 6 6 that would resolve to 1,1,2. I don't know how that ends up as a zero/false for the No response. Can you help me get my head around that please?

Comment: You are thinking wrong on the COUNTIFS.  In this case of 4 numbers it will return 0,1, OR 2.  It only counts if three in a row are above 5.  IF A2>5 AND B2> AND C2>5 then that is 1.  IF B2>5 AND C2>5 AND D2>5 then that is 1.  So it returns either `0` if niether the above are true, `1` if only one is true, or `2` if both are true.  With the IF, `0` is considered `FALSE` anything above `0` is `TRUE`. @JGFMK

Comment: @ScottCraner Ok I get =0 FALSE. <>0 is TRUE (slight correction). But I am still confused. I see 3 range/comparison pairs, but how does that correlate to 3 in a row? I know it works but I'm failing to get it. If A2 & B2 are both <=5 then A2:B2,">5" becomes 0. If one of A2 & B2 are over 5, it gives 1. If both are over 5 it gives 2. If you reduce formula down for data 4,6,7,7.2 in image above, it becomes something like IF(COUNTIFS(1,2,2),"Yes","No"). How is (1,2,2) being reduced to a non-zero value for Yes? By contrast data 6,5,6,6 would reduce to (1,1,2). How does that gets reduced to 0 for No?

Comment: You are still misunderstanding how countifs works.  With each of the three ranges having two cells it compares the first cell in each of the three ranges then moves to the second of each range.  For example `COUNTIFS(A1:A2,1,B1,B2,1,C1:C2,1)` only counts if all the cells in the same row in the three column are 1, not if both cells in each range are 1. @JGFMK

Comment: RIght. I have tried to visualise it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtNeb.png. And I think with that last explanation, the penny has finally dropped.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a variant, all in one cell, :

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A4:D4,">"&5)>=3,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Avoids text and mixed text & numbers...

Apparently 6, 1, 6, 6 does not work re comment below, seems to work:
[image]

Comment: Number 9 does not meet the criteria and should be "NO" this also doesn't work for other cases.

Comment: Thanks, seems that it's working for me.

Comment: @Kevin If you have other criteria then you need to post your own question - the OP seems to think it works for what they want...

Comment: Well then he needs to look at his criteria. Row 9: 6,7,4,8 does not contain 3 consecutive numbers that are greater than 5.

Comment: @Kevin well, in the original post the question asked in the first line is not identical to that asked in the second line...

Comment: This is wrong - 6,1,6,6 does not work!

Comment: 6,1,6,6 should give No. 3 consecutive cells > 5

Comment: @JGFMK not according to the first statement of the OP... There is a difference between the first statement and the second though...

Comment: Quote: "I want to print YES if there is at least 3 time continuous value". The 'positive' example in the screenshot even shows consecutive values..

Comment: @JGFMK Quote : "I want to print YES if there is a value greater than 5 and this value must be present alongside cells for at least 3 times" which you should read as well...

Comment: @AZamanSagor Could you please clarify if my solution does what you want and that the various "interpretations" are just interesting? Thanks.

Comment: It still seems working for me.

Comment: @AZamanSagor Thank you for the reply.